# Is it possible to return similar locations via Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

Given a location e.g. Santa Monica - is it possible to use Google Places API to return other similar locations?

I would be interested in discovering other similar places within X miles. A result set similar to Santa Monica could be Manhattan Beach, Huntington Beach.

In determining what is 'similar', if there were no restrictions in using the API, I would for instance list and group content of the location E.g.
Parks 2
Beach 1
Restaurants 100
Airport 1

Then retrieve locations within X miles that most closely have similar characteristics

Comment: What is "similar"? Place names consisting of two words? Places with beaches? Cities over a certain size? Regions exceeding a specific percentage of paved roads? A range of population density? Number of bars per square mile? Number of corrupt politicians who have lived there in the last hundred years? This is an extremely vague question as posted....

Comment: Would also be interested in an answer to this. Have you found out more @J K? I think of similar places like foursquare's endpoint offers: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/similar